# why (undefined || false) expression didn't work properly?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

actions/index.js

```
export const fetchAppointment = (userId) => async dispatch =>{
const request = await axios.get(`${URL}/apis/appointments/${userId}`)
    dispatch({type :types.FETCH_APPOINTMENT, payload:request.data})
```

};

reducers/reducer_appointment.js

```
import _ from 'lodash';
import * as types from '../actions/types';
export default function(state = null, action) {
    switch (action.type) {
        case types.FETCH_APPOINTMENT:
            return  _.mapKeys(action.payload, 'patients_id')  || false
        default:
            return state;
    }
}
```

app.js

```
    renderAppointment(){
    console.log(this.props.appointment)
    switch(this.props.appointment){
    case null: 
        console.log("null case")
        return;
    case false:
        console.log("false case")
        return <div>false case</div>;
    default:
        console.log("default case")
         return <div>default case </div>;
    }
}
```

the porblem I always get the *default case* although I get data or no data. I wish the false case works when no data.

**Update**

I checked the result, _.mapKeys returns undefined. So I wondered and post this post!

Please help me!

Comment: what does `mapKeys` return? /look at answer from @Krasimir

Comment: @palaѕн I mentioned above that I get the default state result.

Comment: undefined if no data returned, or promise if data returned. Is it OK?

Comment: working on that, just few minutes

Comment: at types.FETCH_APPOINTMENT it gives me [] if action.payload used, and {} if _.mapKeys(action.payload, 'patients_id') used. I will log same inside switch soon for you.

Comment: and if course, when one record is there, I get that console.log as  [12343:{...}] or [{…}]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That is I guess because `_.mapKeys` always returns at least an empty object. So your state is `{}` even if the payload is `undefined`.

Comment: so how can I improve the code to solve the problem! Thanks for reply

Comment: I checked the result, _.mapKeys returns undefined. So I wondered and post this post!

Comment: @Diamond I'll suggest to use a flag and not rely on `null`, `false` and `undefined`. They will for sure produce more bugs. If you wanna dig deeper I'll even point you to this article about using a state machine http://krasimirtsonev.com/blog/article/managing-state-in-javascript-with-state-machines-stent

Comment: As for the _mapKeys I tried it here https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#mapKeys and if I pass `undefined` as first arguments it returned `{}`.

Comment: understood your article, but still struggling how to use it in my case, your help will be appreciated.

Comment: let's say I have 3 cases, waiting for user fetch, displaying a Sign In link, or displaying a Sign Out link.

Comment: any idea how to have a basic example? thank you in advance.

Comment: succeeded in customizing the concept in the article, using redux. i use callbacks to wait for data save/read, and in the callback i call input function and update state. and of course, before calling save/read func, i call input func at redux to put state into loading. i have to call the input func 2 times per transaction that takes time.